# How to Repeat this code after getting Result in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python code to find Exponential Value. Now I want to Re-Run this code automatically after getting result of One Number, means ask for another number infinite times

```
# Function to Find Exponential Value of any Number
def expo(num, exp):
    result = num ** exp
    return result

# Taking Input
Number = int(input("Please Enter Desired Number: "))
Exponent = int(input("Please Provide Power Value: "))

# Passing to Function
ExpoVal = expo(Number, Exponent)

# String Section
str1 = "Exponential Value of %s" % Number
str2 = " with Power of %s" % Exponent
str3 = " is :"
str_concatenate = str1 + str2 + str3

# Output Result
print(str_concatenate, ExpoVal)
```

Comment: you can use `while` or `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the whole code as a single function and then run it through a `while True:` loop. This makes it run infinitely:

```
def Expo():
    Number = int(input("Please Enter Desired Number: "))
    Exponent = int(input("Please Provide Power Value: "))

    result = Number ** Exponent

    str1 = "Exponential Value of %s" % Number
    str2 = " with Power of %s" % Exponent
    str3 = " is :"
    str_concatenate = str1 + str2 + str3

    print(str_concatenate, ExpoVal)

while True:
    Expo()
```

Comment: got it, Shukriyaa, but if there is any code to execute whole code again after completion?

Comment: Do you mean you have some code to execute after the while True loop?

Comment: Also, if this helped, pls mark it as correct (check mark next to the votes)

Comment: got it , in the answer shared below. TYSM for your response.

Answer (score -1):

You should put all of your code into while loop:

```
while True:
    # Function to Find Exponential Value of any Number
    def expo(num, exp):
        result = num ** exp
        return result

    # Taking Input
    Number = int(input("Please Enter Desired Number: "))
    Exponent = int(input("Please Provide Power Value: "))

    # Passing to Function
    ExpoVal = expo(Number, Exponent)

    # String Section
    str1 = "Exponential Value of %s" % Number
    str2 = " with Power of %s" % Exponent
    str3 = " is :"
    str_concatenate = str1 + str2 + str3

   # Output Result
   print(str_concatenate, ExpoVal)
```